# Jenkins - running Cypress tests in Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, cucumber, cypress

In Jenkins I have a docker container, in which I want to run my Cypress tests (cucumber preprocessor).

All feature files are placed in `myrepo/cypress/integration/features/**/.feature`

That means I have multiple subfolders under feature folder and in each subfolder are placed the feature files. (e.g. myrepo/cypress/integration/features/admin/testadmin.feature)

In **package.json** I have defined for scripts test:

```
"test": "node_modules\\.bin\\cypress run --spec \"cypress/integration/features/**/*.feature\""
```

and in jenkins trying to run it via:

```
sh 'docker exec image1 npm run test'
```

But it can't find the feature files.

Then I tried to specify the path directly in the command and changing to cypress run:

```
sh 'docker exec image1 ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/features/**/*.feature" '
```

But I have this error:

```
Can't run because no spec files were found.

We searched for any files matching this glob pattern:

cypress/integration/features/**/*.feature

Relative to the project root folder: /myrepo
```

I also tried it withou quotemarks:

```
sh 'docker exec testrepo ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --spec cypress/integration/features/**/*.feature'
```

Then it says:

```
   Warning: It looks like you're passing --spec a space-separated list of arguments:
    
    "cypress/integration/features/admin/testadmin.feature cypress/integration/features/admin/anothertest.feature ... etc.
    
    This will work, but it's not recommended.
      
    The most common cause of this warning is using an unescaped glob pattern. If you are
    trying to pass a glob pattern, escape it using quotes...

We searched for any files matching this glob pattern:

cypress/integration/features/admin/testadmin.feature, cypress/integration/features/admin/anothertest.feature

Relative to the project root folder:/myrepo
```

So it seems, my first solution with quote marks is correct, and also it knows about the feature files if they are listed there, but still says can't find them.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found out that I forgot to COPY the cypress folder to docker image in Dockerfile. Now it solved everything :)

Comment: Can you please take a look at this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332307/unable-to-run-cypress-cucumber-in-jenkins